# prints line number in both txtfile and list?

Tags: python

i have this code which prints the line number in infile but  also the linenumber in words what do i do to only print the line number of the txt file next to the words???

```
d = {}
counter = 0
wrongwords = []
for line in infile:
infile = line.split()
wrongwords.extend(infile)
counter += 1
for word in infile:
    if word not in d:
        d[word] = [counter]
    if word in d:
        d[word].append(counter)
```

for stuff in wrongwords:
    print(stuff, d[stuff])

the output is :

```
hello    [1,  2,  7,  9] # this is printing the linenumber of the txt file
hello    [1] # this is printing the linenumber of the list words
hello    [1]
what i want is:
hello    [1,  2,  7,  9]
```

Comment: From your question it is unclear what you are trying to achieve ? Are you trying to find the line number at which a word occurs ? 
Also this line looks suspicious to me :
if word not in d:
        d[word] = [counter] 
if word in d: 
        d[word].append(counter) 
You check if the word is in dictionary initalize a list with counter and immediately the next if check adds the counter to the created list. Probably you needed an else instead of "if word in d"

Comment: You have asked 5 questions different questions about this code, and received a lot of great and detailed help. 3 of them have been tagged homework. I think the question should be closed.

Comment: its not the same code ive asked quetions about the same thing involving different codes ive used

Answer (score 0):

Four things:

1. You can keep track of the line number by doing this instead of handling a
   counter on your own:

   ```
   for line_no, word in enumerate(infile):
   ```
2. As sateesh pointed out above, you probably need an `else` in your
   conditions:

   ```
   if word not in d:
       d[word] = [counter]
   else:
       d[word].append(counter)
   ```
3. Also note that the above code snippet is exactly what `defaultdict`s are
   for:

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict
   d = defaultdict(list)
   ```

   Then in your main loop, you can get rid of the `if..else` part:

   ```
   d[word].append(counter)
   ```
4. Why are you doing `wrongwords.extend(infile)`?

Also, I don't really understand how you are supposed to decide what "wrong words" are. I assume that you have a set named `wrongwords` that contains the wrong words, which makes your final code something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
wrongwords = set(["hello", "foo", "bar", "baz"])
for counter, line in enumerate(infile):
    infile = line.split()
    for word in infile:
        if word in wrongwords:
            d[word].append(counter)
```